# Which open source dashboard/BI tools can work with monetDB?

Tags: dashboard, monetdb

I'm trying to create a rich online dashboard to analyze web traffic with monetDB. 
Does anybody know how to integrate with an open source solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use:

- DWH: MonetDB
- ETL: [PDI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/) (Pentaho Data Integration)
- OLAP: [Mondrian OLAP](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/olap.php) ([OLAP schema workbench tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mondrian/files/schema%20workbench/))
- Dashboards: [Pentaho BI Server CE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Business%20Intelligence%20Server/) ([CDF](http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/cdf/): charts portfolio [CCC](http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/ccc/) + maps, etc.)

For a quick start:

1. Fill you DWH (MonetDB) with sample data (One fact table, few dimensions)
2. Create OLAP schema in on the top of the DWH tables using "OLAP schema workbench" tool
3. On Pentaho BI Server CE:

   - Add data sources - DWH connection, OLAP schema
   - Create dashboards (according to samples on BI Server)

Comment: Yes, that was what i tried but i got an error, i'll try again. Thanks a lot for the quick start :)

Comment: What issue have you been facing? MonetDB connection? Have you already solved it?